# How to take an PHP output and show it in an ul

Tags: php

I have a simple php script for pinging a ip address but how do I take the output and display if it's online of offline in an unordered list in html

```
   <?php


function ping($host)
{
        exec(sprintf('ping -c 1 -W 5 %s', escapeshellarg($host)), $res, $rval);
        return $rval === 0;
}


$host = 'www.example.com';
$up = ping($host);
?>
```

Comment: You are asking how to do a [loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)?

Comment: please use curl. and set a curl timeout to know if your server is down or not

Comment: Well that depends, are you intending to do it in in real time (the page refreshes itself with new values) or run time (the page processes received data and displays it, statically)?

Comment: I'm adding a refresh timer so yeah in realtime

Answer (score 0):

The result of the command is in your variable $res, just take it ;)